# Replicating RNN within PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, rnn, pytorch

I tried to create a manual RNN and followed the [official PyTorch example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html), which tries to classify a name to a language. I should note that it does indeed work. I'm not using the final logsoftmax, since I use nn.CrossEntropyLoss() and that should apply that automatically (it gives exactly the same results).

```py
class ManualRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, batchSize, inputSize, outputSize):
        super(ManualRNN, self).__init__()
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.inputSize = inputSize
        self.hiddenSize = 64

        self.hidden = nn.Linear(self.hiddenSize + self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize)

        #I tried using both, the first one is from the example suite
        #self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hiddenSize + self.inputSize, outputSize)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hiddenSize, outputSize)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        x = x.view(1, -1)
        hidden = hidden.view(1, -1)
        combined = torch.cat( (x, hidden), dim=1)

        newHidden = self.tanh(self.hidden(combined))
        #output = self.linear(combined)
        output = self.linear(newHidden)
        return output, newHidden

    def InitHidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(1, self.hiddenSize)
```

My goal is to tie this out vs the internal RNN module, so I used `tanh()` for the hidden layer, since that's what the documentation shows for [nn.RNN](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.RNN). I also tried making the input for the final linear layer only dependent on the hidden layer which seems to be what nn.RNN is doing, but I might be wrong - in either case I tried both.

Now I attempted to tie this out vs the nn.RNN module (or should I say cell?):

```py
class TorchRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputSize, hiddenSize, outputSize):
        super(TorchRNN, self).__init__()
        self.inputSize = inputSize      #number of possible letters, i.e. 31
        self.hiddenSize = hiddenSize    #64
        self.outputSize = outputSize    #18 (number of classes)

        #this should be applying tanh() at each time step
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=self.inputSize, hidden_size=self.hiddenSize, batch_first=True)

        #note that here I am only using hiddenSize, because that's the output from nn.RNN ...?
        #that's why in the ManualRNN example above I tried the same
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hiddenSize, outputSize)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        output, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)

        output = self.linear(hidden)
        return output

    def InitHidden(self, batchSize):
        return torch.zeros(1, batchSize, self.hiddenSize)
```

I made sure to use only names with 5 letters, and using the final hidden layer as input, since I didn't want to further confuse the situation with pad_packings.

With enough iterations both, the `ManualRNN` and `TorchRNN` models perform similarly well. However, they don't tie out. There shouldn't be any randomness and I checked that the inputs are being fed in the same order. I am using the following to establish seeds (even though I am not using cuda on this machine):

```py
np.random.seed(666)
torch.manual_seed(666)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(666)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

What am I doing wrong? My understanding is that the [example from the website](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) isn't actually replicating the `nn.RNN` class properly. `nn.RNN` outputs seem to be `hidden_for_each_k` and `last_hidden`. The last element of `hidden_for_each_k` is the same as `last_hidden`. Consequently it seems that the only inputs available for the linear layer are last_hidden - which is not the same as in the tutorial, hence I changed the input for the linear layer in the ManualRNN to accept only the hidden layer. However, even that doesn't tie out. The values are completely different for basically any point in time.

So in short: Is there a way to go from "manual RNN" to "nn.RNN" so that the results tie out exactly? Any way you could show this to me would be appreciated (it doesn't have to be the same example).